# How do I download Adobe Lightroom Classic for MacOS on a Windows PC

Tags: windows-10, macos, download, adobe-lightroom

I am on a Windows 10 Pro PC and wish to download Adobe Lightroom Classic for a friend who is having download issues on his MacOS device.  Does Adobe provide this capability?  I tried and it seems that there is no way to do this.  Adobe apparently senses the OS of the system requesting the download and only offers OS-compatible apps for download. If you know of a way around this behavior, I'd welcome your insights.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to gain access to the stand-alone installers to CC2020 is to contact [Adobe's Customer Care](https://helpx.adobe.com/contact.html). All their agents are authorised to give out temporary direct download information to customers who need these for reasons such as this - or for archiving or installation on multiple machines.

How you achieve this to be able to download on behalf of someone else I'm not sure - though one would imagine if your friend can get the link, he can pass it to you before it expires.